# limit checkbox and uncheck after changing tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show and hide divs with select tag. In the divs there are check boxes which has a logic of disabling them after the user checked 2. When I am changing the divs the checkboxes are staying disabled. For some reason the max 2 checkbox logic is disabling all the checkboxes.

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/yJCYW/

The Jquery looks somewhat like this

```
$('.selectOption').change(function(){
        $('.descContent').hide().eq(this.selectedIndex).show();
        $('.resourceMsg').hide();
    });

    var max = 2;
    var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

    checkboxes.change(function(){
        var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);

        if(current >= max){
            $('.resourceMsg').show();
        } else{
            $('.resourceMsg').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can they select two for each select option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just uncheck the checkboxes and set the disabled property to false whenever the select element is changed:

```
$(function () {
    var max = 2;
    var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $('.selectOption').change(function () {
        checkboxes.prop({
            'disabled': false,
            'checked': false
        });
        $('.descContent').hide().eq(this.selectedIndex).show();
        $('.resourceMsg').hide();
    });
    checkboxes.change(function () {
        var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);

        if (current >= max) {
            $('.resourceMsg').show();
        } else {
            $('.resourceMsg').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yJCYW/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, didnt think about it like this. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

You have no code to enable them.

```
checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
```

This will disable *all* unchecked checkboxes on the page, and not just those in the currently displayed `div`.

You need to reconsider what should occur upon the selection change; you either need to throw away existing selections or re-enable checkboxes (effectively the same thing):

```
$('.selectOption').change(function(){
    $('.descContent').find(':checked,:disabled').prop({checked: false, disabled: false});
    $('.descContent').hide().eq(this.selectedIndex).show();
    $('.resourceMsg').hide();
});
```

Alternatively, you could just disable the checkboxes in the current `div`.

```
checkboxes.change(function() {
    var content = $(this).parents('.descContent');
    var current = content.find(':checked').length;

    content.find(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);

    // ...
}
```